# What compile-time type must I assign to receieve a return value of java.util.Map<TextAttribute, ?>

Tags: java, generics, kotlin

I'd like to make a font derived out of another font. Here's what I am trying to do:

```
val font : Font = this.label.getFont();
val attributes : Map<TextAttribute, Any> = font.getAttributes();
attributes.put(TextAttribute.UNDERLINE, TextAttribute.UNDERLINE_ON);
this.label.setFont(font.deriveFont(attributes));
```

However, the Kotlin compiler complains at the line:

```
val attributes : Map<TextAttribute, Any> = font.getAttributes();
```

With the message:

```
 Type mismatch: inferred type is 
(Mutable)Map<TextAttribute!, *>! but 
Map<TextAttribute, Any> was expected
```

Per my limited understanding of generics in Java, I understand that font.getAttributes() returns a `java.util.Map<TextAttribute, ?>`; the latter type parameter means *when you create a bounded / closed generic type out of this map, please specify as the second type parameter, anything that extends java.lang.Object*.

So, when I tried with the following line at first:

```
val attributes : java.util.Map<TextAttribute, Object> = font.getAttributes();
```

The Kotlin compiler said:

> This class shouldn't be used in Kotlin. Use kotlin.collections.Map or kotlin.collections.MutableMap instead.

and it also said:

```
 Type mismatch: inferred type is 
 (MutableMap<TextAttribute!, *>..kotlin.collections.Map<TextAttribute!, *>?) 
 but java.util.Map<TextAttribute, Object> was expected
```

I have no idea what the `!` symbol means and that wildcard asterisk symbol means. What is it saying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem is that the [`getAttributes`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#getAttributes()) method returns a map that can hold nulls whereas `Map<TextAttribute, Any>` declares that its values must not be null. 
The second problem is that the [`Map`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-map/) interface in Kotlin does not allow mutation.

To resolve the problems change your code to e.g.:

```
val attributes : Map<TextAttribute, *> = font.getAttributes();
val updatedAttributes = attributes.plus(TextAttribute.UNDERLINE to TextAttribute.UNDERLINE_ON)
```

or even more concise:

```
val updatedAttributes = font.attributes.plus(TextAttribute.UNDERLINE to TextAttribute.UNDERLINE_ON)
```

Finally since Kotlin has handy extension methods the whole font mangling can be turned into:

```
label.font = label.font.run { 
    deriveFont(attributes.plus(TextAttribute.UNDERLINE to TextAttribute.UNDERLINE_ON)) 
}
```

Comment: I saw its extension methods syntax and it looks likes `fun TheClassToExtend.yourExtensionMethod() { ... }`. I also came across this `run { }` block a couple of times I can't remember where -- whether it was the documentation or the code recommender within the IDE. I still don't know what those are and have to study them. Thanks so much. :-)

Comment: As a side note, you can use `attributes + (TextAttribute.UNDERLINE to TextAttribute.UNDERLINE_ON)`

Comment: Won't it copy the whole map on `plus`? A `MutableMap` may be for fitting here

Comment: @voddan it will but I'm pretty sure that's not going to be a bottle neck here.

Answer (score 1):

I looked up [Star Projections](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#star-projections) in the Kotlin documentation and from a quick reading, it appears that it is Kotlin's way of introducing variance into generic types, so the asterisk `*` in an `out` position means `out Any?`, so I changed my code to this and it worked:

```
val attributesMap : Map<TextAttribute, Any?> = font.getAttributes();
val attributes : MutableMap<TextAttribute, Any?> = 
      attributesMap as MutableMap<TextAttribute, Any?>;
```

And also there was that the compile-time type I used was a read-only interface `kotlin.collections.Map<K, V>` where as I was putting items into it. But that was something I was mindful of and was about to take care of once I'd gotten rid of the casting error in the previous line.